# Merge factor, minMergeDocs, Lucene

Tags: lucene

I am unable to understand the difference between mergefactor and minMergeDocs.

For e.g. I want to index 10,000 Documents and say 100 of those Documents fill up my RAM buffer, so Lucene will write out these 100 Documents as a file. Now if I set mergefactor=5, when a fifth segment is to be written to the disk, Lucene will merge all the existing segments to a single segment and so on.

**1.** Where does minMergeDocs fit in to this? If I have mergefactor=5 and minMergeDocs=10 -- Does mergefactor take precedence over minMergeDocs?

**2.**  Also, when Lucene merges segments on the disk , does it also delete the individual segments, which are now part of the new segment file?

Thanks in advance for your response,

Answer (score 2):

Merge factor defines how often the segments will be merged. Default value is 10. That means, a new segment is created for every 10 documents. When the number of such segments reaches 10, the segments themselves are merged to create a single segment of 100 docs. This is the Log Merge Policy.

minMergeDocs no longer exists in Lucene 3.0.

To have finer control on indexing, you can use `setMaxBufferedDocs()` or `setRAMBufferSizeMB()` or `setMaxMergeDocs()` methods from [IndexWriter](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html).